# Java run after fixed period, or a criteria met

Tags: java, methods, timer

In Java,

I wan't to run a method after a fixed period, UNLESS another criteria is met.

The criteria is that a buffer array is larger than a certain size.

I am not sure which constructor is best to use. I want something such as:

```
public void init(){
    Start timer.
}
public void check(){
    If (Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length) > 500 ){
        stop timer 
        run method
}
public void timerExpired{
       run method
}
```

The constructs I thought of are Timer, and cancelling, using ScheduledExecutor, but unsure if there are any other suitable data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)? Behind that link there are mentions of other possibilities such as CyclicBarrier.